# Microsoft UI Automation framework in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, uwp, ui-automation, uia

The current codebase completely relies on C# using .NET.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview

Is there any npm library that allows to use microsoft UIA (user interface automation) framework using any of the below.

- javascript
- typescript
- Nodejs

Comment: You could use some adapter, like Edge, for example: https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge

Comment: @Haroldo_OK Thanks mate , this is one of the possible ways i can do. But preferably i am trying to look for any existing npm library that can do the job. I will stick along with your approach incase i am unable to get one.